# Inclusão de primeiro Registro utilizando um select SUM

Tags: sql, pl-sql, trigger, oracle11g

Em determinada rotina eu tenho uma trigger que executa um código semelhante a esse abaixo.

Estou com problema no primeiro registro, como no primeiro registro não tem qualquer código, a soma de `+ 1` não está sendo realizada, e eu não consigo fazer o insert.

Tem algum modo de jogar um valor default, ou algum recurso do Oracle que contorne quando a inserção for no primeiro registro?

```
INSERT INTO TABELA1                                                                  (
 CODIGO
,CAMPO2
,CAMPO3)

VALUES

(
(select max(CODIGO)+1 from TABELA1)
,VALOR2,
VALOR3)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Para casos como esse, você pode utilizar da função `NVL`:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

---

Utilizando dela, você gera um valor default caso o `MAX` retorne `null`, logo seu insert ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA1 ( CODIGO ,CAMPO2 ,CAMPO3)

VALUES

( (select nvl(max(CODIGO),0) +1 from TABELA1) ,VALOR2, VALOR3) );
```

Dessa forma, quando o `max` retornar `null`, ele será substituído por zero e sua soma irá retornar 1.

---

[Veja esse exemplo online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b3dd1/2).

Comment: muito obrigado a todos, o nvl resolveu meu problema, depois disso eu tb resolvi utilizar a criação de sequencia, e também funcionou bem.